# Reading comma separated values file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am getting an error while reading this csv in jupyter. it is a large file of 1MB so I dont know if i need to add something else other than the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/okekec/Downloads/Week5-Visualization/Week5-Visualization/Indicators.csv")
```

---

```
> ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-2-f86d364577b0> in <module>()
>       1 import pandas as pd
> ----> 2 df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/okekec/Downloads/Week5-Visualization/Week5-Visualization/Indicators.csv")
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names,
> index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine,
> converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows,
> nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
> skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
> date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
> decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment,
> encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines,
> skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray,
> compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map,
> float_precision)
>     653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>     654 
> --> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     656 
>     657     parser_f.__name__ = name
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
> in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     409 
>     410     try:
> --> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
>     412     finally:
>     413         parser.close()
```

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of the csv file that you are trying to import?

Comment: And please format your question.

Comment: The data is from kaggle, here is the link : https://www.kaggle.com/worldbank/world-development-indicators                                  Under data sources select Indicators csv